# Rails app doesn't refresh correctly when one character is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I'm working on my app I try to refresh the browser it uses the old code when only one character is changed.

For example I had a typo and got the error:

> undefined method `All' for #

and it highlights the code as the problem

```
@locations = Location.All
```

The problem is the capital letter. In my file I changed it to lowercase so it's correct. I refresh the page and still get that same error and the line that's highlighted with the problem is still capitalized. If I change it and add like a third l Ill get the expect error can'y get method alll. Then If I change it back to all It will work correctly.

Same thing happens with when tweaking css. If I change a value for a color from 3 to 4 it wont update the color. I have to change from 3 to 34, refresh, back to 4 and refresh for it to work

Ive been doing a lot of searching but can't find anything really related or helpful.All I did find was to use development mode which Im pretty sure Im using. Happens in diffrent browsers too.

Full trace for the error. File has the correct code.

```
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/api/v1/citys_controller.rb:6:in `index'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

environment.rb :

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development"
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
Rails.application.initialize!
```

development.rb :

```
Rails.application.configure do
 config.cache_classes = false
 config.eager_load = false
 config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
 config.active_support.deprecation = :log
 config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
 config.assets.debug = true
 config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

Comment: Have you saved your file, if you use text editor like vim or ..., make sure you first save your file

Comment: Yeah I'm saving the file

Comment: You should not have to restart server unless you change "config" or "Gemfile", try hard refresh with F5 and with hitting enter, sometimes browser is caching files.(Can't think anything else)

Comment: Didnt change anything. It works they way it should. Just only when I'm changing an uppercase to lower case or something simmilar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you meant the:

```
@locations = Location.all
```

Some ideas:

1. `All`, along with `Location` is a class name, or constant. I believe you wish to call a class method called `all`.
2. If the error persists anyway, restart the server, because it seems that the server has cached the code in the controller/model.
3. Please fix the environment config by disabling class caching, [eager loading](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/08/eager-loading-for-greater-good/) (for Rails 4), and [cache performing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) as follows:

   ```
   config.cache_classes = false
   config.eager_load = false
   config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
   ```

Comment: @user3803703  Are you sure that you start the development env?

Comment: Those are false already for the development.rb And I believe so. The line when i start the server says "=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000"

Comment: @user3803703 and you have started webrick?

Comment: When I start the server It says booting webrick and three lines lines of INFO webbrick

Comment: @user3803703 try this in config: `config.cache_store = :null_store`

Comment: Tried that. Didnt fix it. Thanks for helping btw